# Prevent server from terminating on request overload

Tags: java, server, glassfish, payara

Is there a configuration that will prevent Payara Server from terminating its process when overloaded with request?

When Payara is overloaded with request it gets terminated and a manual `./asadmin start-domain` command is required to up it again.

So is there a way to prevent it from terminating but just don't accept more requests?

Comment: Are you sure that Payara terminates itself? I'm not aware of anything like that in Payara. Can you check whether it's terminated by the OS? Maybe due to out of memory or some OS rules? In cloud, for example, default OS configurations usually kill processses that exceed quotas for resource usage.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the thread pool used by the Payara Server HTTP listener to decrease the maximum size (maximum number of threads) and also maximum queue size. If there are no free threads and the queue is full, new requests will be refused.

You can follow GlassFish documentation for configuring thread pools, it applies to Payara Server too: https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/glassfish/docs/latest/administration-guide/threadpools.html#ggkyc

You'll need to update the following properties with the set command:

- `configs.config.server-config.thread-pools.thread-pool.http-thread-pool.max-queue-size`
- `configs.config.server-config.thread-pools.thread-pool.http-thread-pool.max-thread-pool-size`

You can list all of the properties using the get command with `*` suffix:

```
bin/asadmin get 'configs.config.server-config.thread-pools.thread-pool.http-thread-pool.*'
```